# Fill empty array with multidimentional dictionary Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

I'm trying to fill out a table view with some Brand Names inside sections.

For now i have this dictionary

```
var manNames = ["A":["ABERCROMBIE & FITCH MEN","ACQUA DI PARMA MEN","ADAM LEVINE ΜΕΝ","AIGNER MEN","ANTONIO BANDERAS MEN","ARAMIS MEN","ARMANI GIORGIO MEN","AZZARO MEN"],"B":["BALDESSARINI MEN","BALDININI MEN","BENTLEY MEN","BOTTEGA VENETA MEN","BOUCHERON MEN","BREIL MILANO MEN","BRUT MEN","BURBERRY MEN","BVLGARI MEN"]]
```

Which conforms in this struct

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}
```

Having this empty dictionary of objects

```
var objectArray = [Objects]()

I fill it in with the following for loop

                let sortedNames = atoz.manNames.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
                for (key, value) in sortedNames {
                        objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
                }
```

Then i populate the data in the table and all good till now.

In cellForRowAt this is how i take each brand name

```
cell.companyName.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to make each brand name to have its own ID, so when The function `didSelectRowAt` is executed, I would like to send this id to the next view controller, and not the name of the brand.

To be more precise.

```
AMBERCOMBIE has the ID 40
ACQUA DI PARMA has the ID 200
```

etc.

How can I edit my existing dictionary for each brand name to have its own ID and then to take it from the array `objectArray` ???

Comment: Your "array" is not an Array. It is a `[String : [String]]` dictionary.

Comment: @Fogmeister you are correct i will edit now. My bad.

Comment: Also, why not send the name across? What would you do with the unique id when the other view controller receives it?

Comment: @Fogmeister make a request at my API. Those dictionaries will be dynamic that's why i want to send ID's and not names

Comment: In that case I would not store it in a dictionary like that at all. Store an array of objects (not strings) and give each object a name and an id.

Comment: @Fogmeister could you answer with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the first thing to do in any problem like this is to define your model.

In this case your model is a `Manufacturer` (I'm guessing from the "man" in your code) ... also, don't abbreviate variable names, it makes them hard to read. If something is a "manufacturer" call it a "manufacturer".

So, it needs a name and an id...

```
struct Manufacturer {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
}
```

Next you need a directory of these stored with the initial letter as a way of indexing them into sections...

```
struct DirectorySection {
    let initialLetter: String
    let manufacturers: [Manufacturer]
}
```

and...

(Again, notice the descriptive naming)

Now you need an array of these to work with...

```
let directory: [DirectorySection] = [
    DirectorySection(initialLetter: "A", manufacturers: [
            Manufacturer(name: "Abercrombie & Fitch", id: 40),
            Manufacturer(name: "ACQUA DI PARMA MEN", id: 50),
            Manufacturer(name: "ADAM LEVINE ΜΕΝ", id: 60),
            ....
        ]),
    DirectorySection(initialLetter: "B", manufacturers: [
            Manufacturer(name: "BALDESSARINI MEN", id: 130),
            Manufacturer(name: "BALDININI MEN", id: 131),
            Manufacturer(name: "BENTLEY MEN", id: 132),
            ....
        ]),
    ....
]
```

Of course, you could define this in a plist file if you wanted or in a dictionary, or a CoreData store, etc... Doing it code is just as good for now if it doesn't change. Just make sure to create the model this way whichever way you want to store it.

Now you have everything you need set up.

To get the manufacturer from the indexPath...

```
let manufacturer = directory[indexPath.section].manufacturers[indexPath.row]
```

To populate the cell...

```
cell.textLabel.text = manufacturer.name
```

To pass the manufacturer to the other controller...

```
controller.manufacturer = manufacturer
```

Whenever you are dealing with a `Manufacturer` you are passing a full `Manufacturer` around. You need the name? It's there. You need the id? It's there.

Once you have a decent data model the rest is simple.

**NOTE**

The main thing to take away from this. Don't use names like `objectArray` or `atoz` or `manNames` or `Objects`. It just makes things hard to understand. There is nothing bad about using long, descriptive names. And there are many good things about them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I was reading your answer I also made this code but I was confused with the array. Now its clear for me! Thanks a lot again

Comment: thumbs up for the `NOTE` section